# Use DataTrigger in DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatrigger, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a datagrid as follows,

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSet.Rows}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle2}" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" EnableRowVirtualization="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="30*"  Header="{StaticResource RangeColumnHeader}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle2}" SortMemberPath="StartValue">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedSet.IsDefault}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedSet.IsDefault}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DatGrid>
```

I Want use " SelectedSet's " IsDefault property to set cell's IsEnabled property.

I tried above code, which is not working.

Classes are defined as follows,

```
public class UCSetModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private Set _SelectedSet;
    public Set SelectedSet
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedSet;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedSet = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSet");
        }
    }
}

 public class Set
{
    private ObservableCollection<Markers> _rows;
    public ObservableCollection<Markers> Rows
    {
        get
        {
            return _rows;
        }

        set
        {
            _rows = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Rows");
        }
    }

    private bool _isDefault;
    public bool IsDefault
    {
        get
        {
            return _isDefault;
        }

        set
        {
            _isDefault = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsDefault");
        }
    }   
}
```

I want to bind to a property of the same 'SelectedSet' that the rows come from.

Comment: Is `Set` a property of the individual rows/items? Or shall all cells in that particular column be enabled/disabled at the same time?

Comment: Did you check the output window for binding errors?

Comment: Set is an object which is defined in view model and 'Rows' is Set's property which is an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup you have posted won't even compile. This does:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDefault}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

`IsDefault` is supposed to be a property of a `Row` object, i.e. you should remove "Set." from the binding path assuming that a row doesn't have a `Set` property.

If you want to bind to a property of the same `SelectedSet` that the rows come from, the binding should be defined like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SelectedSet.IsDefault, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: My point is I Want use " Set's " IsDefault  property to set cell's IsEnabled property.

Comment: @SAT: So why didn't you tell...? See my edited answer.

Comment: Your answer explains my question more accurately than my actual question. However the solution doesn't work.

Comment: Then you need to tell us what doesn't work and what "doesn't work" actually means and how your classes are defined. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Change the binding path to `SelectedSet.IsDefault` then. See my edit.

Comment: Your solution didn't work in my case. Cell was always enabled.

Comment: @SAT: Put "DataContext" in front of the rest of the binding path. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedSet.IsDefault,ElementName=SetWindow}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
   </DataTrigger>
```